# vue good table - filterDropdownItems return incorrect values

Tags: vue.js, vue-good-table

```
filterDropdownItems: [
   {'value': 'active', 'text': 'Active'},
   {'value': 'inactive', 'text': 'Inactive'}
]
```

When I select *Active* it display also *Inactive* values. Here is working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/b90fa2er/2/

Any advice how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a filter function.

```js
data: {
  methods: {
    columnFilterFn(data, str) {
      if (str === 'active') {
        return data === 'Active'
      } else {
        return data === 'Inactive'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As an aside, You might want to store your active state in another field and not the name. Use the `id` for your data instead of the `name`. Then in the filter function, lookup the object `rows.find(it=>it.id === data)`